# Can't Boot 16.04 server from USB 3.0

Tags: boot, 16.04, server, usb, sd-card

I have a 16.04 server set up on an SD card. I put the SD card into a Transcend USB 3.0 card reader. When I plug the reader into the USB 2.0 port on my physical server box, it works fine. When I plug it into the USB 3.0 port on that same server I get a ton of errors and it eventually just hangs indefinitely.

The errors have a few different variations.

Version 1:

```
Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
(1 of 3) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid...
(2 of 3) A start job is running for udev Kernel Device Manager (10s / 1min 32s)
(3 of 3) A start job is running for Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd of progress polling...
1: device not accepting address 2, error -62
b8-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[69...] scsi 2:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
[69...] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 4206688
[69...] EXT4-fs error (device sda1): ext4_find_entry:1451: inode #1603: comm lvm: reading directory lblock 0
[69...] Buffer I/O error on dev sda1, logical block 0, lost synce page write
....
```

Version 2:

```
[OK] Reached target Sound Card.
(1 of 5) A start job is running for Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data...
(2 of 5) A start job is running for dev-disk-by\x2duuid...
(3 of 5) A start job is running for LSB: AppArmor initialization (12s / no limit)
(4 of 5) A start job is running for Set console font and keymap (13s / no limit)
(5 of 5) A start job is running for Flush Journal to Persistent Storage (15s / 1min 33s)
-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[68...] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sda1-8.
[68...] Aborting journal on device sda1-8.
[68...] Buffer I/O error on device sda1. logical block 53913
[68...] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for sda1-8.
....
```

In several places it says "Maybe the USB cable is bad?" I've tried several different readers. I know they all work with 2.0 so I doubt it's actually a problem with the reader. I also tried the second USB 3.0 port in the same server and it had the same problems. So I doubt it's a hardware problem, unless the whole box is broken.

Comment: It's probably just a USB 3 compatibility problem. Have you checked for a BIOS/firmware update for your motherboard? Are you willing to try booting to a Ubuntu 16.10 Live DVD and see if the USB 3 problem gets any better?

Comment: I have a few adapers/card readers. All work when the card is connected as a data drive, but it is more tricky to *boot* via the adapters. Some can boot some computers, others can boot other computers. None of my card readers can boot all the computers I have tested. Adapters with the brand names Transcend and Kingston are among the best, but this is a trial and error area.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out heynnema was right. The company that makes the board I was using released a BIOS update 5 months after I posted this. When I update the BIOS it works just fine.